# Chart.JS full-width, responsive doughnut chart with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I'm using the [Angular.js variant](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js) but the core of Chart.js is exactly the same.

I have a simple doughnut chart, that I'm using within a responsive Bootstrap container:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
       <div class="chart-container">
          <canvas id="doughnut" 
                  chart-data="data" 
                  chart-labels="labels" 
                  chart-options="mainDonut" 
                  class="chart chart-doughnut">
          </canvas>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing fancy. My controller options are:

```
 $scope.mainDonut ={
    percentageInnerCutout : 90,
    responsive: true
}
```

It seems like the width of the chart is limited to whatever the height of the div is, which for me is magically being set at about 300px by ChartJS for some reason. Here's how it renders:

[image: chart.js responsive with bootstrap]

I want the height to be responsive to whatever my `.col-xs-8`'s width is, and fill the entire div. **I understand that I can do this with Javascript** by watching for window resize events, but I want to avoid that if possible.

Any solutions here?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to make it responsive and preserve aspect ratio, 2 things to consider:

1) In `options`:

```
{
   responsive: true,
   maintainAspectRatio: true, 
}
```

2) Define the aspect ratio by setting `width` and `height` attributes to the `canvas`. In your case they're probably equal:

```
<canvas id="doughnut" 
    width="100"
    height="100"
    chart-data="data" 
    chart-labels="labels" 
    chart-options="mainDonut" 
    class="chart chart-doughnut">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the width of the chart is limited to whatever the height
>   of the div is, which for me is magically being set at about 300px by
>   ChartJS for some reason.

That's the default width of the canvas element (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-canvas-element).

This means that your `responsive` option is not actually doing what it's supposed to. The most likely reason is that the the wrapping element does not have a (measurable) size when the chart is being initialized. For Angular, the most common reason is the wrapping (parent) elements not being in a fully rendered state when the chart is being initialized (eg. it has an `ng-show` or it's a hidden tab, etc.).

CSS on the parent element could also be a problem - e.g. the parent elements don't have a size (but looking at your markup this seems a bit unlikely)

---

Note - even though you don't do a chart resize on window resize, Chart.js automatically does it for all charts that are configured as responsive.

Answer (score 1):

```
function initChart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('chart-canvas');
    canvas.width = parent.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = parent.offsetWidth; ... 
}

+css parent block {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 300px;
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: When I try to update my 100% width chart on event it gets blurry and cut off. I use this approach, and work like a charm. Thanks. `ctx.canvas.width = document.querySelector(".chart").offsetWidth; ctx.canvas.height = document.querySelector(".chart").offsetHeight; chart.update();`